# Convert visualization of a DataPicker in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, datepicker

I created a Datepicker which gets opened when a user clicks on a button. The problem is that I would like to convert it to a spinner (without showing the year) instead of this visualization:
[image]

How can I modify it?

```
dateSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                           //TODO
                        }
                    }, year, month, dayOfMonth);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

I also created a style for it, but I don't know how to connect it:

```
<style name="MySpinnerDatePickerStyle" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MySpinnerDatePicker</item>
</style>

<style name="MySpinnerDatePicker" parent="android:Widget.Material.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Assuming you're using the platform class, it should be `new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, R.style.MySpinnerDatePickerStyle, ...)`. You're just inserting your theme resource ID as the second argument in the constructor call.

Comment: It compiles, but nothing changed

Comment: Hmm, it works as expected for me. Are you sure you used `R.style.MySpinnerDatePickerStyle` there, not `R.style.MySpinnerDatePicker`?

Comment: Yes, it shows me the calendar instead of the spinner

Comment: Well, I'm not sure that I can suggest anything further, as I can't reproduce the issue. Which Android version are you testing on?

Comment: I'm on Android 7.1

Comment: Well, I ran my test on 8.0, and if it works on that, I would really expect it to work on 7.1, as the only "breaking" changes I know of happened in later versions. Which specific folder do you have those `<style>` elements in? I mean, are they possibly in a `res/value-v??/` folder? If so, what's that version?